# How can I extend Dictionary to work with Intervals

Tags: swift

I want to extend **Dictionary** to support native **Interval** types such as **HalfOpenInterval**, **ClosedInterval**, so I can do something like this:

```
var dict = [
    0.0..<1.0 : "Okay",
    1.0..<2.0 : "Better",
    2.0..<3.0 : "Perfect"]

for (range, value) in dict {
    print("\(value) is assigned to \(range)")
}
```

The Dictionary key type must conform to **Hashable** protocol, and I'm thinking that I can make a hash value using composition of **start** and **end** properties if they also **Hashable** using code:

```
public var hashValue: Int {
    let halfshift = sizeof(Int)*4
    return start.hashValue ^ ((end.hashValue << halfshift) | (end.hashValue >> halfshift))
}
```

My best attempt to achieve this (full code):

```
extension IntervalType where Bound: Hashable {

    public var hashValue: Int {
        let halfshift = sizeof(Int)*4
        return start.hashValue ^ ((end.hashValue << halfshift) | (end.hashValue >> halfshift))
    }
}
extension HalfOpenInterval: Hashable where Bound: Hashable {}
extension ClosedInterval: Hashable where Bound: Hashable {}
```

is not working because of
**error: extension of type 'HalfOpenInterval' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause**

Considering initial approach is not realizable in **swift 2.2** What else I can try keeping it close to original use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend `Range` to make it `Hashable`:

```
extension Range: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return "\(self.startIndex)_\(self.endIndex)".hashValue
        }
    }
}
```

If you are running Swift 3 Alpha, replace `startIndex` and `endIndex` with `lowerBound` and `upperBound`.

(edited) In Swift 2 `Range<Double>` is not possible, but `IntervalType` can be extended same way

```
extension IntervalType {

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(self)".hashValue
    }
}
extension HalfOpenInterval: Hashable {}
extension ClosedInterval: Hashable {}
```